# Unable to change graphics renderer to nvidia from llvmpipe; Debian 11; nvidia 1650 gpu

Tags: debian, nvidia

I am using Debian 11 and I am unable to switch my renderer from llvmpipe to nvidia. Please, how can I start using my nvidia graphics card so I can get back to my work using Blender??

Output of `glxinfo -B`:

```
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: Mesa (0xffffffff)
    Device: llvmpipe (LLVM 11.0.1, 256 bits) (0xffffffff)
```

```
OpenGL vendor string: Mesa
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 11.0.1, 256 bits)
```

Ouput of `nvidia-smi`:

```
NVIDIA-SMI 535.98    Driver Version: 535.98    CUDA Version: 12.2
```

Answer (score 0):

With an nvidia version of 535.98, I'd guess you installed the nvidia driver from nvidia's own web site - really not a good idea.

Or maybe from some Ubuntu PPA or other non-Debian distro, an almost equally bad idea - Debian and Ubuntu are not the same.  Yes, Deian and Ubuntu and several other distros use `apt` and `dpkg` and `.deb` packages.  That doesn't mean packages for one are compatible with another.  They're not, they're built against different versions of libraries with different versions of compilers and have different packaging policies.  Source packages, i.e. `.dsc` files, can be modified as necessary, rebuilt and installed, but binary packages from other distros should not be installed, as they will likely break in obvious or, worse, subtle & hidden ways.

See [Don't Break Debian: Don't use GPU manufacturer install scripts](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_use_GPU_manufacturer_install_scripts).

Your best option to fix this is to uninstall the version you downloaded and re-install the Debian packaged version from the `non-free` section.

Then, if you really **need** a newer nvidia driver and/or Blender, upgrade to Debian 12 (bookworm), which has [nvidia 525.125.06](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/nvidia-graphics-drivers) and [Blender 3.4.1](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/blender)

BTW, with the release of Debian 12, `nvidia-graphics-drivers` moved from the `non-free` section to `non-free-firmware`. You'll need to add that to your sources.list as it didn't exist in Debian 11.